# Getting “I won't open a connection to” when connecting to FTP server with VPN

Tags: vpn, ftp, connection

I am trying to connect to an FTP server using Core FTP while connected to the CyberGhost VPN. The closest I get is using Active mode (passive just times out) but then I get the error:

> 500 I won't open a connection to 10.129.X.XXX (only to 38.XX.XX.XX)
>
> PORT command failed

38.XX.XX.XX is the simulated IP address that CyberGhost gives me. I have no idea what 10.129.X.XXX is.

Is there something I can configure on my end, or will the server just not allow it?